# Does invoking KafkaProducer.send should be synchronized?

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-kafka

I have created an @ApplicationScoped bean which holds KafkaProducer object created with specyfic config, lets name it KafkaProviderBean. Now i want to share that producer provider across all application and use its send method which uses KafkaProducer.send - My question is: should I synchronize access to KafkaProducer.send() or synchronize whole sendKafkaMessage method? I would like to understand it well. Thanks.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class KafkaProviderBean {
private Producer kafkaProducer;
private boolean sendingEnabled;

public Future sendKafkaMessage(ProducerRecord<Object, Object> record, Callback callback) {
        return sendingEnabled ? kafkaProducer.send(record, callback) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: [KafkaProducer#send()](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) is itself asynchronous, why would it need to be syncronized?

Comment: Thank You, I thought so that synchronization is not needed I am not expert in concurrency so I wanted to be sure. I have spent a lot of time in the front of computer and I have became suspicious if Im correct. For example do I still need to synchronize access to the producer object in such case. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The [Producer is thread safe](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html): "The producer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance across threads will generally be faster than having multiple instances."